# how to add custom container above main tag and below header tag in default.xml magento 2

Tags: magento2.2

I want to display homepage banner but this section need to be displayed after header tag and before main tag. The banner I have added via Magento2 Admin -> Content -> Block. Someone help me to solve this issue.

```
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceContainer name="header.container">
        <container name="header.containerabc" as="header_containerabc" 
                   label="Page Header Container Abc"  htmlTag="header" 
                   htmlClass="abc" after="header.container"/>
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
            </arguments>
    </block>
    </referenceContainer>
 <referenceContainer name="header.containerabc" before='main' after="header.container">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="home_banner">
          <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">home_banner</argument>
          </arguments>
        </block>
 </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="footer">
        <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="footer_links" template="Magento_Store::switch/stores.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="header-wrapper" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="logo" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="skip_to_content" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
    <move element="copyright" destination="before.body.end"/>
    <move element="authorization-link" destination="before.body.end"/>
  </body>
</page>
```

But the above code doesn't work.

Comment: Have you try head.additional block refrence?

Answer (score 1):

try below one:

```
<container name="header.containerabc" as="header_containerabc" label="Page Header Container Abc" 
htmlTag="div" htmlClass="abc" before="main.content" after="header.container"/>
```

Comment: in which file this has to be added?

Comment: @Amit Bera:   You miss Double Quote here:  after="header.container

Comment: @RaviSoni thanks for note. The post is updated